# Create this simple array

Tags: python, statistics, quantile

I have two one-dimensional arrays `u` and  `q` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
n = 300
u1 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 4.5, size=n)
u2 = 2 / u1 + np.random.normal(scale=0.09, size=n)
u = np.array([u1,u2])
```

and

```
d=np.random.uniform(0.0, np.pi, size=100)
    q = np.array([np.cos(d), np.sin(d)])
```

I have the following

```
np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.99))
```

for `q[:, 0]`, but I want to have it for every `q[:,m]` from m=1 to 100 (I mean for all columns of `q`) and save them all in a new array.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to be human-readable. TeX formulas are not supported here.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor I've done it and added my try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do and what result you expect. I'm going slow with my explanation so that if I got your idea wrong, you can modify my code to suit your need.

---

Replace `np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]` with:

```
np.dot(q.transpose(), u)
```

The shape of `np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]` is `(300)`, and that of `np.dot(q.transpose(), u)` is `(100, 300)`. This basically dot-product each of 100 columns of `q` with `u`.

Replace your quantile operation with:

```
np.quantile(np.dot(q.transpose(), u), q=0.01, axis=-1) 
# or q=0.99 for the other one
```

By specifying an axis, you restrict `quantile` to only operate on that axis, rather than on the entire array. The result has shape `(100)`.

Before, your quantile operation returns a scalar, so wrapping it in `np.max` does nothing. Now it returns the max of a 100-size array. The final line should be:

```
np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q.transpose(), u), q=0.01, axis=-1)) 
- np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q.transpose(), u), q=0.99, axis=-1))
```

The result is a scalar.

Comment: Dear @FelixFourcolor , thank you very much for your explanation. I've learnerd good points from your answer. Appreciate it. Actually I'm trying to compute  `np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, m],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, m],u[:,]), 0.99))` for all 0<m<100 (which is a scalar for each m). Now I have 100 scalars that I want to have them in a vector. This is what I want. I would be very grateful if you could guide me again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For example, `np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.99))` is `-5.052827539398788` and `np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 1],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 1],u[:,]), 0.99))` is `-4.8180541665607715` and so forth. Now how can I a vector `(-5.052827539398788,-4.8180541665607715 , ... )`?

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you're trying to do?

`np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 1],u[:,]), 0.01))` returns a scalar, then what's the point of wrapping it in `np.max`? I've alluded to this in my answer.

Comment: If you just want an 100-size array of `np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.99))` for each column of `q` , simply remove the two `np.max`es in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. sorry if I I bothered you. As you told, I wanted an 100-size array of `np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.01))-np.max(np.quantile(np.dot(q[:, 0],u[:,]), 0.99))` for each column of `q`. You helped me a lot. Appreciate it.